# How to convert items from earlier editions to 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, conversion

There's lots of fun stuff in earlier editions, like 3 variants of Excalibur and rainbow armor... How can I convert that stuff to 5th edition?

Comment: Absolutely a duplictate of [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110852/are-there-additional-guidelines-for-converting-older-editions-equipment-to-5e) question, but it doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @Marq not a duplicate because this "is there" the other asks "is there anything but..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wizards of the Coast did release a [guide](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_Conversions_1.0.pdf) to convert the mechanical side of items, races, classes and monsters.

For items it reads:

> Equipment should be swapped for fifth edition equivalents.
>   The DM handles the conversion and distribution of gear
>   that isn’t in the Player’s Handbook.
>
> **For the DM: Equipment Conversions**
>
> As DM, you can allow characters to retain any gear and loot
>   with which you are comfortable. Swap magic items for fifth
>   edition equivalents. The rules in the “Starting at Higher
>   Level” section of chapter 1 in the Dungeon Master’s Guide
>   are a fine way to establish a character’s starting wealth and
>   gear in a fifth edition campaign. In most cases, the high
>   magic option is the best choice for representing treasure
>   distribution of previous editions.
>
> For mundane equipment, most such gear converts easily,
>   since it has pragmatic (and narrative) effects rather than
>   broad mechanical ones. Use existing equipment as guides,
>   and when necessary, create mechanics appropriate to fifth
>   edition. Remember to use advantage instead of flat bonuses.
>   Also, try to limit mechanical effects to at or below those of
>   common magic items.