# Can I drop an object and cast Catapult on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, spellcasting, action-economy

I'd like to drop an object weighing 1-5 pounds and use my action to cast Catapult on the item. PH 190 details Other Activity on your turn, and interacting with an object is included on that list. Can I use this Other Activity to remove a one pound rock from my pocket and drop it on the ground in front of me?

Comment: Related: [Is dropping a weapon “free”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70237)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You can pull something out of your pocket then catapult it

The rules for [Interacting with Objects Around You](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#InteractingwithObjectsAroundYou) gives pulling something out of your backpack, or a pouch as valid examples.

Dropping something is easy, so easy that [the lead designer believes it takes no effort](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/70239/59609).

So yes, you can pull out a rock, drop it, and can cast catapult on it.